# Android Intent to other class not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent to another class and all it does it just flag up errors.
I am using some code that i got from a answer to a question i [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174061/calling-an-activity-from-a-service).

My package name is :  `com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService`

The class i am trying to call is :  `.Hello`

Below is how i am calling the class, buts its not working.
I am not an expert in android so a explanation in beginners terms would be appreciated.

```
Log.i("Service", "onStart() is called"); 
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
callIntent.setClassName("com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService", ".Hello");
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: what is the package name for the activity .Hello?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
callIntent.setClassName("com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService",
                "com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService.Hello");
```

Instead of

```
callIntent.setClassName("com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService", ".Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService", 
"com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService.Hello");
startActivity(intent);`